# Stop /sbin/agetty and log out the session

Tags: linux, debian, console, logout, getty

I start `agetty` using `/sbin/agetty 115200 /dev/ttyS2 vt220` to provide `console` access through my port `ttyS2`.

From the other computer, I can create a connection, and upon opening, I am prompted with the login console.

However, if I close the connection and just `kill -9 $PID` the `agetty` and then restart it, and then reconnect, I'm left with where I had left things, with the existing session still active. I need to fully terminate `agetty` and log out the session that it launched. If another connection opens up, I want the login prompt again.

So how do I cleanly terminate `agetty`?

Comment: To clarify, you're able to kill agetty, but you want it to log out any session as it dies?

Comment: Exactly. I want the sessions associated agetty to die as well.